# Bleachbit for Ubuntu is not detecting installed software and not deleting System cache

Tags: 16.04, google-chrome, cache, cleanup, bleachbit

BleachBit is not listing all of the software I have installed that needs to be cleaned such as Google Chrome, Firefox, Flash etc.. Also, it is not removing System cache files or `.bash_history` even though the box is checked. I have to manually go to `~/.cache` to remove these files. It is annoying because I have a bunch of thumbs images and temp files that are unneeded.

[image]